# Sync Fx: Succeesfully synchronize but no data were synchronize

Tags: c#, winforms, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I've made an winform application for data synchronization with offline scenario using sync fx. The problem is that when I synchronize the database, the application give me a message that said that the application were successfully synchronized (complete with number of rows successfully synchronized) but when I check at my database the data is not synchronized and still the same.  Any idea why this is happened?

And I want to know, what possibilities will makes the data failed to synchronize?

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the ApplyChangeFailed event of your providers to see if an error or conflict is encountered during the sync.

You might want to expound as well what databases are you synching (sql ce?, sql express, server, localdb, Azure?) and what change is failing (inserts, updates, deletes?)

Comment: thanks JuneT. I already use the applycahngefailed event on my apps and it's seems like there's no conflict/error occured. I'm synchronizing between sql server and sql server. any idea?

Comment: when you do an update, have a look at the corresponding tracking table if its being updated. if it's being updated, have a look at the ChangesSelected event if the change is being selected. did you initialize your databases properly? no restored copy? youre not updating PKs?

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure that I initialize database properly and not updating PK. Anyways, this not happen every time. I try for many times but sometimes my database can be synchronized successfully.